# with_items not working in windows host for creating directories

Tags: ansible

```
- name: Creating folders DBF & INDEX
  win_file:
   path: "{{item.path}}"
   state: directory
 loop:
   - {path: 'C:/XOFFICEDB/DBF'}
   - {path: 'C:/XOFFICEDB/INDEX'}

- name: Creating folders DBF & INDEX
  win_file:
   path: "{{item.path}}"
   state: directory
  with_items:
   - {path: 'C:/XOFFICEDB/DBF'}
   - {path: 'C:/XOFFICEDB/INDEX'}
```

none of them is working, may I know why ?

```
ERROR! 'with_items' is not a valid attribute for a Play
```

is the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is wrong: with_items should apply to your task win_file. Here it applies to your play. So you should indent the with_items block. For example:

```
- name: Creating folders DBF & INDEX
  win_file:
    path: "{{item.path}}"
    state: directory
    with_items:
      - {path: 'C:/XOFFICEDB/DBF'}
      - {path: 'C:/XOFFICEDB/INDEX'}
```